# Laptop keyboard spams enter. How to disable the key?

Tags: keyboard, hardware-failure

My laptop (ASUS ROG GL752VW) started spamming NumpadEnter hundreds of times a second. I detected which key it is with this website: https://keycode.info/.

I don't want to replace the keyboard and was wondering if I could somehow disable this key.

Right now I have an AutoHotkey script in my autostart with the following content:

```
NumpadEnter::Return
```

It makes the laptop usable again. But I have two problems with it:

- It does not work on the windows login screen.
- When I am logged in the NumpadEnter still gets triggered when I release the shift key.

I also tried the Windows [PowerToys](https://github.com/microsoft/PowerToys). But there I could not find the NumpadEnter to remap it.

Do you have any ideas on how I could use my laptop pain free again?

Here is what the keyboard physically looks like:

[image]

Comment: When you say “spams” you means it just magically and without pause hit’s “Enter?” Sounds to me like a physical keyboard issue. I would recommend shutting down the PC, removing the problematic key and physically cleaning it. Heck, sometimes just removing the keycap and placing it in place again will make it work like normal again.

Comment: Idk if i can remove the keycap. This is the keyboard:
https://ae01.alicdn.com/kf/HTB1G4c4KpXXXXahXVXXq6xXFXXXC/New-Laptop-Keyboard-for-Asus-GL752-GL752VW-GL752VW-DH71-GL752VW-DH74-With-Red-Backlit.jpg
.

Comment: You can *always* remove them… whether you break the mechanism underneath whilst doing it is actually a separate issue ;)) You could try powering it all down, then dousing liberally with contact cleaner, tap firmly on the key a couple of dozen times. Allow 24h to be absolutely certain it's all dry, then power up.

Comment: It is normally wisest in the medium / longer term simply to replace the keyboard and get on with ordinary stuff.